# How can I resolve this definte integral?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

$$ \int (t^2-3)^3 t dt$$
$$ \int_a^b (t^2-3)^3 t dt$$
if $$ a = -1$$
$$  b=1$$
then
$$ \frac 1 2\int (t^2-1)^3 2t dt$$
$$ \frac 1 2 \frac {u^{3+1}}{3+1}$$
$$ \frac 1 8 u^{4}$$
$$ \frac 1 8 (t^2-1)^{4}$$
$$ \frac 1 8 [(1^2-1)-(-1^2-1]$$
$$ \frac 1 8 [(0)-(0)]=0$$
or
$$ \int (t^2-1)^3 t dt$$
$$ \int (t^4-2t^2+1)t dt$$
$$ \int t^5dt-2\int t^2dt+\int tdt$$
$$\frac {t^6}6 - \frac{2t^4} 4 + \frac {t^2} 2$$
a=-1, b=1
$$\frac {1^6}6 - \frac{2(1)^4} 4 + \frac {1^2} 2 -[\frac {-1^6}6 - \frac{2(-1)^4} 4 + \frac {(-1)^2} 2]$$
$$\frac 1 6 - \frac 1 6 = 0$$

is it a error?
I think  that area cannot be zero, 
I already tried the change of variable method,
that gives me a & b = 0

Comment: Note: $(t^2 -1)^3 t = t^7 - 3 t^5 + 3t^3 - t$. You merely took the square, instead of the cube.

Comment: ...
ok.. that is a "tonto error" :/

Comment: @CalvinLin is
$$(t^2-1)(t^2-1) = t^4-2t^2+1$$
$$(t^4-2t^2+1)(t^2-1) = t^6 - 3t^4 + 3t^2 - 1$$
$$ (t^6 - 3t^4 + 3t^2 - 1)t = t^7 - 3t^5 + 3t^3 - t$$
...

Comment: Yes, note also that in the top, you used $(t^2-3)^3t$, which later became $(t^2-1)^2t$. Be careful with carelessness.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function you are integrating is an **odd** function. (A function $f(t)$ is *odd* if $f(-t)=-f(t)$ for all $t$.) 
If $f(t)$ is an odd (and say continuous) function, then 
$$\int_{-a}^a f(t)\,dt=0$$
for all $a$. So you did not even need to integrate.

**Remark:** If you find the result troubling for your particular application, it may be that the integral was not set up properly. In particular, it is easy to make a mistake calculating the area between two curves $y=g(x)$ and $y=h(x)$, if in part of the domain $g(x)\gt h(x)$, and in another part of the domain the inequality runs the other way. The integral  that gives the area is $\int_a^b |f(x)-g(x)|\,dx$.

Comment: ok, thanks for solve my question, there is no an application for this integral

Comment: Well, then the integral is $0$ for "general" reasons. You can alternately make a substitution, like you did, or expand the cube and integrate term by term.